# simplest python equivalent to R's gsub

Tags: python, r, python-2.7

Is there a simple/one-line python equivalent to R's `gsub` function?

```
strings = c("Important text,      !Comment that could be removed", "Other String")
gsub("(,[ ]*!.*)$", "", strings) 
# [1] "Important text" "Other String"
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

For a string:

```
import re
string = "Important text,      !Comment that could be removed"
re.sub("(,[ ]*!.*)$", "", string)
```

Since you updated your question to be a list of strings, you can use a list comprehension.

```
import re
strings = ["Important text,      !Comment that could be removed", "Other String"]
[re.sub("(,[ ]*!.*)$", "", x) for x in strings]
```

Comment: It looks like `re.sub` has a count argument. In R, `gsub` removes all instances of the pattern, so `gsub("th", "", "this that other")` would return "is at oer". Do you know the argument for count that would tell python to remove all instances of the pattern?

Comment: @Imo per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) -- "The optional argument count is the maximum number of pattern occurrences to be replaced; count must be a non-negative integer. If omitted or zero, all occurrences will be replaced. Empty matches for the pattern are replaced only when not adjacent to a previous match, so sub('x*', '-', 'abc') returns '-a-b-c-'."

Comment: What if I want to apply this to a whole list/column and not just to one string?

Answer (score 13):

`gsub` is the normal `sub` in python - that is, it does multiple replacements by default.

The method signature for `re.sub` is `sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0)`

If you want it to do a single replacement you specify `count=1`:

```
In [2]: re.sub('t', 's', 'butter', count=1)
Out[2]: 'buster'
```

`re.I` is the flag for case insensitivity:

```
In [3]: re.sub('here', 'there', 'Here goes', flags=re.I)
Out[3]: 'there goes'
```

You can pass a function that takes a match object:

```
In [13]: re.sub('here', lambda m: m.group().upper(), 'Here goes', flags=re.I)
Out[13]: 'HERE goes'
```